# Adding a Text Area to FlowLayout Panel Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a text area to a Panel that has flow layout, but its not showing on my GUI...any ideas pls?

```
private void makeTypes() {
    westPanel.setVisible(false);
    centerPanel.setVisible(false);
    northPanel.setVisible(false);
    contentPane.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    // set panel layout and add components
    centerPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    northPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    /**
     * Adding East Panel
     */
    eastPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

    /**
     * Adding text area to Centre Panel
     */
    a1=new JTextArea();
    centerPanel.add(a1);
    a1.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

centerPanel is invisible:

```
centerPanel.setVisible(false);
```

And so nothing added to it will show.

I see that you call `setVisible(true)` on the JTextArea, but this will have no effect if it is being added to an invisible container since it too will be invisible.  Other suggestions: Give your JTextArea decent row and column property values, something that could be done via its constructor that takes two ints (for row and column). And wrap the JTextArea within a JScrollPane and add **that** to the GUI. If this code is called during program run and not at startup, then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after adding and removing components.

For more and better help, consider creating and posting a valid [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Hannah: then let's see your [sscce](http://sscce.org), code that we can compile and run and see your problem for ourselves.

Comment: @Hannah: also you never tell us when this method is called, if it's at GUI start up or during GUI run. If during run, then call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container after adding and removing components.